# Find the transformation that converts a square with diagonal vertices (0 , 3) and (-3 , 6) into a unit square at the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the transformation that converts a square with diagonal vertices (0 , 3) and (-3 , 6) into a unit square at the origin.

Comment: What are diagonal vertices?

Answer (score 1):

The desired transformation is a translation followed by a dilation. The translation maps the center of the first square, $(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{2})$, to $(0,0)$, so it is of the form $f(x,y)=(x+\frac{3}{2},y-\frac{9}{2})$. Then, because the side length of the first square is $3$ and of the second is $1$, we divide all coordinates by $3$. The entire map is
$$
f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{2},\frac{y}{3}-\frac{3}{2})
$$